# input box in sharepoint to add entry, popup

Tags: javascript

I have a button, when i click on button i need a popup which should have textbox and a button "ok". in textbox i can enter numerical values like 10, 12 etc and click on ok button. Later ok button click fires a method. It is possible?
Can anyone tell me the steps and code to perform the same. any javascript? i have to integrate this feature in one sharepoint webpart. Do i need to write any javascript for the same?

Comment: of course you can make a dialog window and have there some input. what did you do so far?

Comment: i have not started it yet, can you let me know the process and code for the same please

Comment: what do you want to do with this values??

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short hint for your solution:
HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="test" value="klick"></input>
<label id="label"></label>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("test").onclick= function (){
var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "Harry Potter");
if (person != null) {
//do some stuff if ok is clicked and value entered  
        document.getElementById("label").innerHTML =
        "Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";
}
};
```